# How to export my SQL table as a CSV fie using PYTHON

Tags: python, sql, csv

I have quite a small table, with 5 columns (inlcuding the primary key) and I am trying to export the data into a CSV file

```
import csv
with DbManager(#MY DATA BASE INFO) as db:
            SQLview = 'SELECT * FROM mytable;'
            db.cursor.execute(SQLview)
            writer = csv.writer(db)
            writer.writerow([ i[0] for i in cursor.description ]) 
            writer.writerows(cursor.fetchall())
```

However I am getting the error

```
writer = csv.writer(db)
TypeError: argument 1 must have a "write" method
```

TIA for any help or if you can point me in the right direction :)

Comment: What do you expect `csv.writer(db)` to do? You want to write to a file, not back to the database.

Comment: @AlexHall I used the documentation and thought that would create the file using the db data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to open a file to output the data :

```
with DbManager(#MY DATA BASE INFO) as db:
    SQLview = 'SELECT * FROM mytable;'
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(SQLview)
    with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow([ i[0] for i in cursor.description ]) 
        writer.writerows(cursor.fetchall())
```

Comment: I will accept your answer in two minutes when the timer allows me :)